# Dynamic OLEDB source to Dynamic Flat Files

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

This seems to be a popular topic of question but I haven't found one asked yet that quite attempts to do what I am doing.  Hope this isn't a duplicate, here goes!

The basic premise of my issue is that I have a table in SQL Server that contains a list of table names.  What I want the SSIS package to accomplish is to read in these table names (as well as other variables such as start and end dates) and then output a report for each table filtered on the dates aforementioned.

To work towards that end so far, I have setup Execute SQL tasks which populate my variables with their necessary values.  One of which is an Object type variable which gets a full result value from an Execute SQL task against the table that has the list of table names.

Then a Foreach loop uses that Object variable as its collection loop.  I then take the current loop index (table name) and assign it to a variable which gets fed into a Data Flow OLEDB source whose data access mode is set to SQL Command from variable.  This variable is a short little report that incorporates previous variables to filter the result set.

It fails at this point however because of I suspect two things: 
1) I had to put a "default" table into the table name variable to get the package to validate in the first place to execute it.  This table conflicts with whatever table gets selected to iterate first because it's non-deterministic?  So the difference in metadata fails the task.

2)The metadata is not being updated at run time.

The reason I tried to do it this way is because there are over 200 tables I need to extract data from and into separate flat files which will be named according to the date range they are run for, the table they come from, and various other identifying variables.

That would get arduous and messy if I had to build separate data flows for each individual OLEDB-FlatFile pair.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am attempting?  Or would I be served dynamically building and executing BCP commands?

Thanks!

Comment: As you've discovered, you can't update metadata at runtime in SSIS. You can use BIML to build your packages dynamically beforehand and run them, or you can use a different tool (BCP is just one, I would use VBScript or Powershell)

Comment: I guess I'll start looking into this.  It seems counter intuitive to me that SSIS must re-map columns despite the destination being a free form brand new file destination each time.  But that's just me complaining.

Comment: SSIS is an ETL tool and is therefore _very_ picky about metadata. If you have mapped columns with slightly different datatypes you need to explicitly define the rules that convert the datatypes (i.e. do I truncate the data or throw an error). You can't just have the tool randomly decide what happens. You _could_ take this a step further and just write some SQL that dumps your report as one single enormous varchar field. Then your metadata never changes. But then you need to incorporate any mapping logic in your SQL